# Should I do some sort of mixed effects model or repeated Anova with my data?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am wondering if I should be doing a mixed effect model or repeated ANOVA with my data. I am looking at feeding in sponges, particularly picoplankton which are in 5 groups (Pro, Syn, Euk, LNA, HNA). I collected water samples after it has gone through the sponge from 2 different genera of sponges from two different regions. The genus being Callyiospongia or Iricina and the region being the Red Sea or the Caribbean. My question is if there is a difference in feeding preference between the two genera or between the two regions the sponges are from. So there is one dependant variable which is retention efficiencies(RE)(a percentage) and the independent variables would be region(2 levels), genus(2 levels), and food(5 levels). The thing I am concerned about is that we get the 5 RE dependant values for each of the food levels from each sponge we sample so for each sponge we have a RE value for Pro, Syn, Euk, LNA, HNA. I just want to know if it would be inappropriate to run it as a three-way factorial ANOVA since we have 5 values from one sponge. The sponges prefer some food types over others generally but there is still differences among sponges in their consumption of the different food types. so we want to test the differences between the 5 food types for each sponge.

```
str(REdata)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   240 obs. of  7 variables:
$ sample    : chr  "F1" "F4" "F7" "F9" ...
$ Region    : chr  "Florida" "Florida" "Florida" "Florida" ...
$ genus     : chr  "Cally" "Cally" "Cally" "Cally" ...
$ food      : chr  "Pro" "Pro" "Pro" "Pro" ...
$ RE        : num  93.8 93.1 95 91.6 94.9 ...
$ Redecimal : num  0.938 0.931 0.95 0.916 0.949 ...
$ logittrans: num  2.72 2.6 2.94 2.39 2.93 ...
```

Comment: How many sponges are there?

Comment: There are 16 sponges from each genus in both regions

Comment: That is helpful. Are you working in R? If so, could you post the result of `str(df)`? I think I understand your data, but it would be helpful to see that output.